# How do i create and link another webpage with Visual Studio Code?

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

Currently I am following tutorials online that uses 1 index.html file, and 1 app.js file that results in only 1 page. However I would like to have multiple pages, that links back and forth with a click of a button, how do I have multiple pages?

Do I have to code all the pages in the same index.html file? Or do I need to create another html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Or do I need to create another html?

Yes. Unless you are building a SPA or dynamically generating your HTML with server side code: Each HTML file is a page.

> that links back and forth with a click of a button

[The `<a>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a) is used to create links between pages.

```
<a href="url-of-other-page.html">Other page</a>
```

Comment: Just to clarify my understanding of the answer,the "url-of-other-page.html" is the other named html file
example:
page 1: homepage.html has code,
 <a href="sidepage.html">Sidepage</a>
Brings us into the sidepage.html

Then, would I need to include anything in the other html that it is linked to the first html?

Comment: I have tried to put it into my codes as part of the div and it still is not showing up the link

<div class="content">

            <form id="add-cafe-form">
                <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Cafe name">
                <input type="text" name="city" placeholder="Cafe city">
                <button>Add Cafe</button>
            </form>

            <button>Edit</button>

            <ul id="cafe-list"></ul>

<a href="secondtest.html">Side page</a></div>

Comment: Shows up fine when I test it: https://jsbin.com/zeqakugite/1/edit?output

Comment: That's a quirk of jsbin. My demo was for the sake of demonstrating that the link does show up.

Comment: Hi @Quentin, sorry but I tried turning it into a button, and it doesnt work. Did some research and many claims that hyperlinks cannot be nested into a button, how should I do this then?

Comment: @BasirLa — If you want a link use a link. Use CSS to make it look the way you want.