# I'm trying to make a sentence partially a link and the rest normal text, what did I do wrong?

Tags: html, text, hyperlink, inline, display

I'm talking specifically about the part that says `<p>Questions? Ask them <a href="https://www.google.com/">here</a></p>`

```css
.center {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 57%;
}

body, html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0:
}

header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 70px;
    background-color: #00264d;
}

h1 {
    position: absolute;
    padding: 3px;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 2%;
    margin-top: 10px;
    font-family: Arial;
    color: #ffffff;
}

ul {
    width: auto;
    float: right;
    margin-top: 8px;
}

li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 15px 30px;
}

a {
    text-align: center;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 1.2vw;
}

a:hover {
    color: #F0c330;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

img {
    width: 100;
    margin-top: -16px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="SitNumber360Styling.css">
    <title>Sit Number</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="SitNumberLogo.png">
  </head>
  <header>
    <div class="wrap">
      <h1>Sit Number</h1>
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Chairs</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Cushions & Pillows</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Accessories</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Support</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
  </header>
  <body>
    <p>Questions? Ask them <a href="https://www.google.com/">here</a></p>
    <div>
      <img src="transparentchair.png" alt="Product Picture" class="center">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/06/links-should-never-say-click-here/

Comment: Why did someone close my question? [How do i create and link another webpage with Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59731709/how-do-i-create-and-link-another-webpage-with-visual-studio-code) is not related to partially making a sentence a link.

Comment: You want to create a link. That question tells you how to create a link. It's entirely relevant. That that question asks about VS code is by-the-by, it's still just typing HTML. That that question doesn't specifically ask about "part of a sentence" doesn't matter, because how you create a link is the same no matter how much text you want to put into it.

Answer (score 0):

You might try nesting the elements such as;

```
<p>Questions? Ask them <a href="#">here</a></p>
```

Comment: It doesn't work

Comment: @StanleyY — Yes, it does. (If you can't get it to work then you should ask a new question, with [a clear problem statement](http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/) and a [mcve])

Comment: You should put the link which you want to navigate inside the href attribute.